# Linear function $f$ where: $Im f = Im f^{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $f$ is a linear function that maps from the vector space $E$ to $E$ such that $Im f = Im f^{2}$, I need to show that $E = Nucf + Imf$ where $Nuc$ and $Im$ stand for the kernel and the image of the linear function $f$.

I don't know how to approach this exercise...

Answer (score 1):

If $x \in E$ we can write $f(x)$ as $f(f(u))$ for some $u$. Now $x=y+z$ where $y=x-f(u)$ and $z=f(u)$. Can you verify that $y \in Nuc (f)$ and $z \in Im(f)$?

Comment: I'm not understanding this part: $y = x - f(u)$...

Comment: @mozzarino I am just writing $x$ as $(x-f(u))+f(u)$ (just adding and subtracting $f(u)$).

Comment: I see... Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: By definition of the image of a linear mapping $z = Imf$, but I don't see how to verify that $y$ belongs to the $nucf$.

Comment: $f(y)=f(x-f(u))=f(x)-f(f(u))=f(f(u))-f(f(u))=0$. @mozzarino